# How to pivot / un pivot a stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

There is a way to PIVOT / UNPIVOT (explode, traspose) an Stream with Kafka streams?

If I have the input stream with

```
machineId   ts  VarName VarValue
m1  2017-10-01 00:00:00 var1    1.0
m1  2017-10-01 00:00:00 var2    2.0
m2  2017-10-01 00:00:00 var1    3.0
m2  2017-10-01 00:00:00 var3    4.0
m3  2017-10-01 00:00:00 var4    5.0
...
```

I want a way to get the output stream

```
machineId   ts  Vars
m1  2017-10-01 00:00:00 [[var1, 1.0], [var2, 2.0]]
m2  2017-10-01 00:00:00 [[var1, 3.0], [var3, 4.0]]
m3  2017-10-01 00:00:00 [[var4, 5.0]]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregation with output type `List`. Something like

```java
KStream<MachineId, V> inputStream = ...
KTable<MachineId, List<V>> result = inputStream.groupByKey()
                                               .aggregate(...);
```

The `Initializer` returns an empty `List<V>` and the `Aggregator` would append values to the list.

Check out the docs and examples for more details:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#aggregating
- https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples